# Using numeric indexes to pass data from controller to view

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I have a simple question. Let me explain
We use this to pass data from controller to view

```
function index(){

    $data['title'] = 'This is title';
    $data['message'] = 'This is message';
    $this->load->view('test',$data);
}
```

Here we are using Associative Array to pass data
And now this function again and use indexed array instead of Associative Array

```
function index(){

    $data[] = 'This is title';
    $data[] = 'This is message';
    $this->load->view('test',$data);
}
```

And now in View this does not work.

```
echo $data[0];
echo '<br>';
echo $data[1];
```

i only want to know if why this does not work. And in the user guide i never read that associative array is necessary.

Comment: says undefined variable $data

Comment: in codeigniter variable set in contriller will be accessed in view by using the key of associative array like this in controller $data['names']=array(); in view you can access them as $names

Comment: It is because CodeIgniter uses `extract()` on the associative array. `extract` on a non-associative array returns 0, therefore no variables are being created for your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view data are converted into variables when parsed. A similar result of what `extract()` function of PHP gives.  For example:

```
$data['title'] = 'This is the title';
```

will be accessible directly as `$title` **not** `$data['title']`. In fact, if you look at the sources, you will find it does uses `extract()` and similar conversion happens on your case to, but since variable `$0` and `$1` are invalid so they are not available.

Stick to string indexing. If that is not an option, then you might want to prefix something before the texts like:

```
$data['d0'] = 'This is the title';
```

Read the manual [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html) its quoted. However, you can pass an array instead of a string and giving the exact result of what you want.

```
$data['data'] = array('This is the title', 'This is the description');
```

Now, this you will be access using `$data[0]` and `$data[1]`.

Comment: Well thanks for a good idea i always use the same way but i was just curious to know