# Codeigniter: What is the process behind data passing form controller to view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am not actually asking the syntax and the how do it.
That, I got it from: [codeigniter: pass array from controller to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8756207/codeigniter-pass-array-from-controller-to-view)

I need to ask how actually it works and what the reason for the process.

I have a controller class with func..

```
public function index()
{
    //echo 'hello world';
    $this->load->model('Site_model');

    var_dump($this->Site_model->getAll()); // just to troubleshoot

    $data['a'] = $this->Site_model->getAll();
    var_dump($data); // just to troubleshoot

    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

When I try to access the $data array directly in view

It throws error and need to be accessed instead as `<?php var_dump($a); ?>`

Why can't we directly use this

```
public function index()
{
    //echo 'hello world';
    $this->load->model('Site_model');

    var_dump($this->Site_model->getAll()); // just to troubleshoot

    $data = $this->Site_model->getAll();
    var_dump($data); // just to troubleshoot

    $this->load->view('home', $data);
}
```

and access the array as  `<?php var_dump($data); ?>`  directly in view page

Comment: You should actually ask , what is the purpose of using MVC

Comment: Why not the second option .. why extracting.. that could also fulfil that criteria?

Comment: @ShehzadBilal , if you actually learn some basics of MVC, you will realize that controllers should never pass information to view. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The procees that is being used behind is the simple one. It just uses a php function.

```
extract($data);
```

this lets all the keys to be used as variables on view.

See Docs [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Comment: @stackup nothing is wrong with it, feel free to use that in any framework you create. Ellis labs decided to go with this format however, probably because `echo $title` looks neater than echo `$data['title']`

Comment: Out of curisity Actually I tried it .. it was throwing error Undefined variable: data

Comment: So this particular syntax is used by ellis .. I haven't tried another MVC.. Thanks any ways..

Comment: Also see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171832/using-numeric-indixes-to-pass-data-from-controller-to-view) question. It will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of reasons to use extract() here:

1. It allows us to use unnamed arrays in controllers, 
      like: `$this->load->view('home', array('foo' => $bar));`;
2. it's the easiest way to keep the same non-global variable names when passed to another function.

Comment: can you clarify your first point.. Like how to access that array in view and what is its application

Comment: @stackup You may consider this array as a wrapper for your variables to preserve their names. For example, in controller: `$this->load->view('home', array('foo' => 5));` will become `$foo` with value of `5` in view and so on.